# issue with recycler view Pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have recycler view that get data from api ,, and its working ,, the api have a pages so when user swipe i need to call api again with different page number , the pages start from 0 to x number ,, i implement this function , but the data is repeated not get new !! this is my code please help

```
newsReycelerViewAdapter = new NewsReycelerViewAdapter(recyclerViewNews, context, stringsDate, stringsTitle, stringsDetails, stringsImages, new JPANewsFragment());

        recyclerViewNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerViewNews.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewNews.setAdapter(newsReycelerViewAdapter);
        getHtmlNewsData(0);

        recyclerViewNews.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int lastItem = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastItem == stringsDate.size() - 1) {
                    int pagenum = 1 ;
                    getHtmlNewsData(pagenum+1);
                }
            }
        });
```

/////////////////////

```
public void getHtmlNewsData(final int pageNumber) {
        Utils.showProccessDialog(context,getActivity());
        BusinessManager.getNewsDataMethod(pageNumber, new ApiCallResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String StringResponse) {
                String Response = (String) StringResponse;
                if (Response.equals(null))
                {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    html = Response.toString();
                    String[] MainSperatedList = html.toString().split("<div class=\"views-field views-field-field-date\">");


                    for (int counter = 1; counter < MainSperatedList.length; counter++) {
                        String Text = MainSperatedList[counter].toString();
                        String ItemSelected = Jsoup.parse(Text).select("span.date-display-single").text();
                        stringsDate.add(ItemSelected);
                        Log.d("AAAAAAA", ItemSelected);
                    }



stringsDate.addAll(stringsDate);

                    Utils.dismissProccessDialog();
                    newsReycelerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: try this example for pagination : https://medium.com/@programmerasi/how-to-implement-load-more-in-recyclerview-3c6358297f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure about other parts of your code but an obvious issue is here:

```
int pagenum = 1 ;
getHtmlNewsData(pagenum+1);
```

You are always calling `getHtmlNewsData` with argument equal to 2. Instead you should properly calculate it (not setting it equal to 1 every time).

Comment: how to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by deleting this line:

```
stringsDate.addAll(stringsDate);
```